# Update ListView elements every time position change

Tags: android, listview, android-location

I have a `ListView`, in every element of that there is a `TextView`.

I'm looking for a way to update every `TextView` in the list every time the user's position changes. I have already implemented the `permissionRequest` for the Localization Services but I really don't know how to be informed every time the position changes.

I don't share code because I have only a lot of failed attempts.

What is in your opinion the best way to implement this kind of feature?

Comment: Assuming your working with one item inside the listview with a textview as a case study, you can compare the dataset of the item added to the new values from the localization service.If the do not tally, you update the textview at the dataset position.

Comment: so in your opinion i have to use a background services?

Comment: If your item textview requires an instant update when your app is in foreground then you need not move your updates to a background thread/service.

Comment: Right. First of all' thanks for the answers. So what Android functionality you advice me? Can you make me an example? It's one of my first time with Android.